# In jQuery is it possible to set a method as a var?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Let's say I have a lot of instances of `$(this).show("slow", function(){fVar;});` where `$(this)` are different objects at different times, but they all need `.show("slow", function(){fVar;});` and fVar is a previously defined function var.

Is it possible to set `.show("slow", function(){fVar;});` as a var like "myVar" so I could theoretically do something like `$(this).myVar();`

Comment: sure, just wrap it as a plugin.

Comment: See http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring

Comment: I agree with LifeInTheGrey; see http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring

Comment: if `fVar` is a function, why not just do `$(this).show("slow", fVar)`?

Comment: I agree with @thesystem, variables can hold functions, since *functions* are *objects* afterall. So you can reference them just like any other variable.

Comment: I'm actually passing arguments and other functions. For the simplified version, this is it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You sure can.  Check out the [jquery docs](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring)

```
(function( $ ) {
  $.fn.myPlugin = function() {

    // Do your awesome plugin stuff here

  };
})( jQuery );
```

don't forget about proper namespacing! And just use the method that you declare (so mPlugin) just as you would any other JQuery method

Answer (score 0):

I'm not so much into JQuery but try this -

```
$.prototype.myVar=function(){
    //here goes your code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

just create it as a function expression and you can use it wherever you want. this function takes in an event object that is created by an event listener. ie: click functions. use this var as your event function callback and pass in the event object so it knows what to show.

```
var showSlow = function(eventObject){
   $(eventObject).show("slow", function(){
        fVar;
    });
}
```